Presto/Trino 95th percentile calculation
I'm looking to do a simply exclude the worst 5% of values from a query. The query is very simple.
select time_to_detection from detection_stats;

Returns a single column that looks like this.
0
0
463
5760
27
117802
2660
14
29
8888
I've tried approx_percentile as well as various ways to get the data into an array and slice but the dynamic length of the results are a challenge I Don't know how to overcome.
I was able to successfully do this, but it's probably less than ideal.
SELECT MTTD AS "MTTD"
FROM
  (WITH cte AS
     (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                ORDER BY time_to_detection) rn,
                               COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
      FROM itx_ops_metrics.incidents_inc_jira
      WHERE (array_join(involved_teams, ', ') LIKE '%Business Technology%')
        AND time_to_detection IS NOT NULL
        AND (year(created_at) = 2024) ) SELECT AVG(time_to_detection) / 60 AS "MTTD"
   FROM cte
   WHERE 1.00*rn / cnt <= 0.95
     AND (array_join(involved_teams, ', ') LIKE '%Business Technology%')
     AND time_to_detection IS NOT NULL
     AND (year(created_at) = 2024)) AS virtual_table
LIMIT 50000;


Please add some sample data, desired output and details how one turns to another.

I was able to successfully do this, but it's probably less than ideal.
